# How to add several td and tr in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

I have a CSS that looks like this:

**CSS**

```
table {   
 width: 100%;
 font-family: calibri;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 margin-left: 0; 
 font-size: 1.1em;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 1px;      
}

td {  
 text-transform: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 115%;
 word-wrap:break-word;  
 vertical-align: middle; 
 padding: 2px 10px 0 3px ; 
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: 1px solid #6A797F;        
}   

tr:nth-child(odd){
 background-color: #a9c6c9; 
}

tr:nth-child(even){
 background-color: #d4e3e5;
}
```

How can I add a separate `<table>`, `<td>` & `<tr>` somewhere down the CSS file where by I can change the styles to fit the purpose of the design of that specific page. I tried to this solution but it didn't work:

```
.members_col1 tr td{
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 115%;
  word-wrap: break-word;  
  vertical-align: left; 
}
```

`.member_col1` is the `<div>` containing the `<table>` I want to add a new set of styles to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute id or class in your table, then cover them as selectors in the css, for example:

```
<table id="another-table">...

css
#another-table{
....
}
```

or

```
<table class="tables">...
<table class="tables">...

css
.tables{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your html:

```
<table class="newTable">
...
</table>
```

and use this CSS:

```
.newTable tr td{
   text-transform: none !important;
   line-height: 115% !important;
   word-wrap:break-word !important;  
   vertical-align: left !important; 
   }
```

Comment: His problem is not one of specificity. `class element element` = 0.1.2, the default (`element`) is 0.0.1. !important is only useful when specificity fails.